# REST API with SSIS (zappy) SmartFocus

Tags: rest, ssis, ssis-2008

I've been tasked with learning how to use a REST API to send data via an automated process. My background is TSQL, SSRS and SSIS so this is a completely new avenue.

I'm looking at using the Zappy Add in and should be able to get a purchase signed off if I can get it functioning. However as this is a new avenue to me I am struggling to get it working.

I need to upload data via the API from a SQL select. I can create files in the required JSON or XML but interacting with the API is drawing a blank

The API is from SmartFocus - [Smart focus API Guide](https://help-developer.smartfocus.com/Content/PDF/SmartFocus_API__TRANSACTIONAL_SMS_REST_.pdf)

Does anyone here have experience with any of the above and can assist, or point me in the direction of good learning material. I'm keen to learn a solution and improve my skills.

I'm aware this is vague and hope it doesn't get down voted too much. I'm just trying to get some help!